# how to upload a file using codeigniter in a form containing other input fields also in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have been trying to upload a file with a form containing other input fields also,although the other fields are been successfully added to database,file is not been uploaded to the defined path.
can anyone help with the help of a small example

controller:-seller_module

code:-

```
public function get_seller_details()
{
 $business_name = $this->input->post("business_name");
 $business_address = $this->input->post("business_address");
 $pin_code = $this->input->post("pin_code");
 $city = $this->input->post("city");
 $state = $this->input->post("state");
 $pan = $this->input->post("pan");
 $upload_pan = $this->input->post("upload_pan");
 if($upload_pan == "UPLOADPAN")
{
 $this->load->helper('form');
 $config['upload_path'] = 'application/views/uploads/pan';
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
 $this->upload->initialize($config);
 $this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');
 if (!$this->upload->do_upload('pan_proof')) {
 $data['msg'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
 }
 else { 
 $data['msg'] = "Upload Success!";
 }
 $this->load->view('seller_details', $data);
 }
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('business_name', 'Business Name', 'required');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('business_address', 'Business Address', 'required');
 if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
 {   
 $this->load->view('seller_details');
 }
 else
 {      
 $this->seller_model->get_seller_details($business_name,    $business_address, $pin_code, $city, $state, $pan);
 $this->load->view('success');
 }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code so we can understand what you have done

Comment: The User Guide has a good example; http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-process

Comment: provide some code to show what you have done.

Comment: Check the permission of that folder. where your are uploading files.

Comment: all permissions are granted,yet the unable to store files.
fyi, for:- ' if($upload_pan == "UPLOADPAN")  '
upload_pan is the name of a button,whose value is assigned UPLOADPAN,and when the button is pressed,file should be uploaded to the folder,but instead,nothiing is happening

Comment: issue resolved by myself,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is being resolved,it was the UPLOADPAN button,i removed the button and file were successfully uploaded